# Database for video from the internet

Tags: optimization

I am an direction student from India working in advertising. For making treatment note and pitch deck I require a lot of photos for referencing from different videos from the internet readily available. Is there any way where I can add videos from various platforms such as YouTube, Vimeo and others and add tags to each videos so that next time I can search for that specific video at an instant.

For example, for a car commercial if I search car and mountains in that database where I have already added multiple videos from internet and have also added the tags of cars and mountains. It gives me the videos of the car commercial that have mountains in it.

The perfect thing for me would be a place where I can copy paste the url from YouTube and Vimeo and after adding I can give those videos specific tags as per my requirement. And the next time when I search with those tags it filters the urls from those tags.

I am looking for a free way to do it and want to add 100s of videos in it. Kindly let me know if you know how it can be done.

Regards
Sumit Rawat

Answer (score 1):

Usually [one does not save media file to a database directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154707/14998487), but rather a reference to a server path location or external link, the latter would be fitting for your case. No need to download the media, apart of course considering issues with  [link-rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

The solution would be to host a small database ([MySQL](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server) would be a free, open source option) with the following tables:

| tag |
| --- |
| tag_id **PK** |
| tag_name |

| tagged_media |
| --- |
| tag_id **FK** |
| media_id **FK** |

| media |
| --- |
| media_id **PK** |
| media_name |
| media_link |

That way, you can have an infinite amount of tags per media-entry, while still being easily query-able.

E.g., to find all media tagged "car":

```
SELECT m.* FROM media m
INNER JOIN tagged_media tm ON tm.media_id = m.media_id AND tm.tag_id = t.tag_id
INNER JOIN tag t ON t.tag ="car"
```